# determine if all values in array are equal

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following values in a single field from a mysql db

```
$rec1="4/1 @ 4p, 4/7 @ 4p, 4/8 @ 4p, 4/14 @ 4p, 4/15 @ 4p, 4/22 @ 4p, 4/28 @ 4p ";
$rec2="4/1 @ 4p, 4/7 @ 7p, 4/8 @ 4p, 4/14 @ 4p, 4/15 @ 4p, 4/22 @ 4p, 4/28 @ 4p ";
```

I need to determine whether all of the time values are the same and if so return just the single time value, otherwise return the entire string. 
In two records above I would want returned value to be -
`$rec1=4p` (all the times were equal, don't care about the dates)
`$rec2= unchanged` from original `$rec2` above since at least one of the time values is different.

Comment: rather than put all that info into one column you should create a new table of releated records and also use datetimestamp or at least a mysql [dattime format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
$rec1="4/1 @ 4p, 4/7 @ 4p, 4/8 @ 4p, 4/14 @ 4p, 4/15 @ 4p, 4/22 @ 4p, 4/28 @ 4p ";
$rec2="4/1 @ 4p, 4/7 @ 7p, 4/8 @ 4p, 4/14 @ 4p, 4/15 @ 4p, 4/22 @ 4p, 4/28 @ 4p ";

function wtf($over) {
    $split = split(",",$over);
    $times = array();
    foreach ($split as $schedule) {
        $parts = split("@",$schedule);
        $times[] = trim($parts[1]);
    }
    $times = array_unique($times);
    if (count($times) == 1) return $times[0];
    return $over;
}

echo wtf($rec1);
echo "<BR>";
echo wtf($rec2);
```

Verified working at: http://gfosco.kodingen.com/6241557.php

Answer (score 0):

Use either `array_unique` or `array_count_values`